# Prove $f(x)=\begin{cases} x, & x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q\\ p\sin(1/q), & x=p/q\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q\end{cases}$ is continuous at irrational points.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity

The function is defined on $[0,1]$ by $f(x) = x$ when $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = p\sin(1/q)$ when $x=p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $p < q, p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \}.$ My observations so far:

Let $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.$ Then $|f(x) - f(x_{0})| = |x-x_{0}|$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}.$ So we choose $\delta = \epsilon.$ Then $|x - x_{0}| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \epsilon.$

Now I consider the case when $x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}.$ In this case, we have that $|f(x) - f(x_{0})| = |p\sin(1/q) - x_{0}| \leq |p\cdot 1/q - x_{0}| < |1 - x_{0}|,$ since $p < q.$ Now I'm struggling a little to find a suitable $\delta > 0$.. Any HINTS are appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Mimic the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function#Properties) of the continuity of the Thomae's function (a.k.a Riemann function) at irrational points;
- If $x_0\in\mathbb [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ and $x=p/q\in\mathbb Q$, then $$|f(x_0)-f(x)|\leq |x_0-x|+p\left|\frac1q-\sin\frac1q\right|;$$
- $|t-\sin t|\leq t^3$ for $|t|$ very small.

The detailed proof:

> Since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t-\sin t}{t^3}=\frac16$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $$|t-\sin t|\leq t^3,\qquad |t|<\delta_1.$$  Let $x_0\in\mathbb [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ and $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$. We pick $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\min\{\varepsilon,\delta_1\}$. For each $i\in\{1, 2, \cdots, N\}$, there exists $k_i\in\mathbb N$ such that  $$0\leq \frac{k_i}i<x_0<\frac{k_i+1}i.$$ Let $$\delta_2=\min\left\{\left|x_0-\frac{k_i}i\right|, \left|x_0-\frac{k_i+1}i\right|: 1\leq i\leq N\right\}>0.$$  Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2, \varepsilon\}>0$. If $x\in(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)\cap\mathbb Q$ with the unique representation $x=p/q$ where $p,q\in\mathbb N$ are co-prime, then $q>N$ (otherwise contradicts the definition of $\delta_2$) and hence \begin{align*} |f(x_0)-f(x)|&=\left|x_0-p\sin\frac1q\right|\leq |x_0-x|+p\left|\frac1q-\sin\frac1q\right|\\ &\leq \delta+p\frac1{q^3}\leq \delta+2\frac1{q^2}\leq \varepsilon +2\varepsilon^2\leq 3\varepsilon, \tag{1}\end{align*} where we used the fact that $|1/q|\leq 1/N\leq \delta_1$ and $p/q=x<2$. If $x\in(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)\setminus\mathbb Q$, then $$|f(x_0)-f(x)|=|x_0-x|\leq\delta\leq\varepsilon.\tag{2}$$ Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ proves the continuity of $f$ at $x_0\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This is quite the problem.

Comment: Nice approach of using limit for $(x-\sin x) /x^3$. +1

Comment: @SomeDude You're welcome. Glad to be helpful.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for your comment. Cheers :-)